# How to tell wget to use the name of the target file behind the HTTP redirect?

Tags: unix, shell, redirect, wget, redirection

Let's a consider link such as htttp://www.mysite.net/download.php?id=267 that redirects to htttp://www.mysite.net/downloads/myfile.tar.gz

If I execute 'wget "htttp://www.mysite.net/download.php?id=267"' wget will happily download and save the result in a file named "download.php?id=333". Naming this file "myfile.tar.gz" would have made much more sense.

There is of course the workaround of using 'wget -O myfile.tar.gz "htttp://www.mysite.net/download.php?id=267"' but this is not what I want : I want wget to do the right thing automatically.

Is there any anyway to tell wget to use the name of the target file behind the HTTP redirect ?

I there any other similar tool that would do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wget --trust-server-names=on htttp://www.mysite.net/download.php?id=267
```

Or option `trust-server-names` in `~/.wgetrc`.

It may be [a security risk](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2010-2252) if the HTTP redirect goes to `../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: Now I realize that trusting server names was the former default... And I now understand your reference to CVE-2010-2252 on Twitter !

Answer (score 0):

I found that lynx will often get the file behind the redirect too.